# $f : B \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\mathcal L^n(N)=0 \implies \mathcal L^n(f(N))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

> Let $B$ an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f:B \to \mathbb R^n$ measurable and satisfy the property that $N \subset B, \mathcal L^n(N)=0 \implies \mathcal L^n(f(N))=0$, where $\mathcal L^n$ is the Lebesgue measure. We also know that
>
> \[
>     \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\operatorname{diam}(f(B_r(x)))}{r} =0
>   \]
>
> for almost every $x \in B$, where $\operatorname{diam}$ gives the diameter of a set and $B_r(x)$ is the ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.
>
> Show that $\mathcal L^n(f(B))=0$.

I tried to use Vitali Covering Lemma with a fixed radius $r$, combined with the Isodiametric Inequality, but I didn't come to an end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=\mathcal L^n$.

Let $E$ be the set of $x\in B$ such that $$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\operatorname{diam}(f(B_r(x)))}{r} =0.$$ There is a sequence of compact sets $K_n\subset E$ such that $$m\left(E\setminus\bigcup_nK_n\right)=0.$$Since $f$ maps null sets to null sets it's enough to show that $$m(f(K))=0$$for every compact $K\subset E$.

The hypothesis shows that $f$ is continuous on $K$. For $r>0$ define $\rho_r:K\to[0,\infty)$ by $$\rho_r(x)=\sup_{y\in K,0<|x-y|<r}\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|x-y|}.$$The fact that $f$ is continuous on $K$ shows that $\rho_r$ is continuous. Since $\rho_r$ *decreases* to $0$ as $r\to0$ it follows that $\rho_r\to0$ uniformly on $K$ and we're done.

Comment: Thanks! This is really similar to what I thought but I don't understand why the uniform convergence is enough. We can cover $K$ with countably many  balls of radius $\leq \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon|x-y|$. So $m(f(K)) \leq \sum_i (2\delta)^n \epsilon$ that doesn't converge because there are infinitely many terms.

Comment: Just to clarify the notation, normalize Lebesgue measure so the measure of a ball of radius $r$ is exactly $r^n$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ so $\rho_r(x)<\epsilon$ for every $x\in K$ and every $r<\delta$. Cover $K$ by $B(x_j,r_j)$ such that $r_j<\delta$ _and_ $\sum r_j^n < 2m(K)$. Then $f(K)$ is covered by $B(f(x_j),\epsilon r_j)$. So the measure of $f(K)$ is no larger than $\sum (\epsilon r_j)^n\le 2\epsilon^n m(K)$.

Comment: That's what I was missing! Can I really impose that free hypothesis about the sum of the $r_i$ on the Vitali Covering Lemma? I knew I could only take $r_i \leq \delta$ for a fixed $\delta$!

Comment: Ok. The simplest explanation is going to give a constant larger than $2$, which doesn't matter. Surely you believe there are _cubes_ $Q_j$ with $K\subset\bigcup Q_j$ and $\sum m(Q_j)\le 2m(K)$. And by subdividing these cubes we can take them as small as we want. Now for any cube $Q$ there exists a ball $B$ with $Q\subset B$ and $m(B)\le c m(Q)$.

Comment: Oh well I missed that it's the sum of $r_i^n$ and so it's the sum of the volumes of the balls which is less than $m(K)$ of course! Thanks!